# GitHub に push することができない (rejectされてしまう)

Tags: xcode, github

Xcodeで開発をしていてpushしようとしたんですが、下記のような画面になりpushできませんでした。なぜ何でしょうか?
仮説としては、GitHubのアクセストークンのような気がするんですが、どうでしょうか?
よろしくお願いします。

```
The remote repository rejected commits. Make sure you have permission to push to the remote repository and try again
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

google翻訳
リモートリポジトリはコミットを拒否しました。リモートリポジトリにプッシュして再試行する権限があることを確認してください

だそうですよ